# Fidler || Programmatically configure rules || Using Fiddler's Auto Responder Feature Programmatically

Tags: python, ironpython, fiddler

I got this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3DWqYXKarA) reference for creating rules. 
Now if I want to use this feature programmatically then how how to that meaning how one can use Fiddler's Auto Responder Feature Programmatically?
Lets say Python/IronPython or any other language. I just want to update fiddler to make sure any request should respond to 400.

Thanks,
Arfeen.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you'd want to do this programmatically instead of just ticking the checkbox? (The script you'd write invokes properties on the `FiddlerApplication.oAutoResponder` object)

Comment: Hi Eric, I am doing automation. As part of that either i take handle of exe to check the check box or do some manipulation using other way.

Comment: Anyways i got the solution for that- 1st generate the AutoResponder.xml  and by checking the check box and copy the xml to another location. Close the exe (b4 closong uncheck the check box). Now replace the xml with copied xml.Open exe, it check will be selected. And that way i did automation.